# Understanding the graph of a limaçon

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

A limaçon is a graph of a polar equation $r=a+b\cos(\theta)$ or $r=a+b\sin(\theta)$ where $a<b$. It is a smooth curve that looks like a loop that twists to have a loop in the middle as well. How can you know the values of the start and end of the inner loop?

[image: sine function limacon graph]

Comment: @fGDu94 I think a<b not more than - it's what makes it a lemicon.

Answer (score 0):

The loop starts and ends at the origin, so you are looking for the points where $r=0$. That is, 
$$\tag1
a+b\cos t=0,
$$
or 
$$\tag2
\cos t=-\frac ab. 
$$
As the cosine takes each value twice, there will be two solutions to $(2)$, that will give you the two values where the curve enters and exits the loop.